# Activar shorcode con javascript o jquery en wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

No tengo ningun codigo de referencia que me permita desde javascript o jquery activar un shorcode, ya que debo activarlo solo cuando presionen en un `<a id='Editar'>Editar campo</a>` el shorcode es

`[super_form id="2143"]`

Algun codigo de ayuda?

Comment: Eso no es posible, el shortcode es extrictamente php, lo que puedes hacer es crear una función que haga echo del shortcode y al presionar el boton editar cambiar el html renderizado por el echo del shortcode mediante ajax.

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que estaba pensando, se lo de do_shortcode sin embargo no entendi como activar mi funcion cuando presionara en el link

Comment: Tendrás que usar ajax, lee este articulo https://decodecms.com/ajax-en-wordpress-de-manera-correcta/ y si luego tienes problemas entonces puedes reformular tu pregunta esta vez demostrando tu trabajo de investigación y código, tampoco esta de mas que leas [ask]

Comment: Wao amigo, muchas gracias, esos pequeños tutoriales nunca pasan por mi mente cuando busco algo especifico, pero por lo que estoy leyendo veo que explica muy bien lo que más o menos trato de hacer, gracias